# Fractional knapsack implementation in java (But not correct answer)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, knapsack-problem, greedy

I am having problems with a fractional knapsack implementation in java. I am not getting the correct answer.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import static java.lang.Integer.min;

public class FractionalKnapsack {

    // this method for calculating the maximum index

    public static int select_max_index(int[] values, int[] weights, int n) { 

        int index = -1;
        double max = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

            if (weights[i] > 0 && (double) values[i] / (double) weights[i] > max) {

                max = (double) values[i] / (double) weights[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }

    private static double getOptimalValue(int capacity, int[] values, int[] weights, int n) {

        // fractional knapsack problem
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####"); // for getting the decimal point upto 4 digits
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
        int i;
        double value = 0.0000d;
        if (capacity == 0)
            return value;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int max_index = select_max_index(values, weights, n);// call the maximum index
            if (max_index >= 0) {
                int b = min(capacity, (weights[max_index]));
                value = value + b * ((double) values[max_index] / (double) weights[max_index]);
                weights[i] = (weights[max_index] - b);
                capacity = capacity - b;
            }
        }
        return Double.parseDouble(df.format(value));
        //return value;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int capacity = scanner.nextInt();

        int[] values = new int[n + 2];
        int[] weights = new int[n + 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            values[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            weights[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(getOptimalValue(capacity, values, weights, n));
    }
}
```

Inputs:

```
3 50
60 20
100 50
120 30
```

Correct output:

> 180.0000

my output:

> 200.0

I have followed all the steps. But  there are 2 issues:

1. Rounding off up to 4 digits after point.
2. For some values there is a big gap between my answer and expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this knapsack with replacement? Usually in fractional knapsack once you choose an item you cannot choose it again. In your  implementation of select_max_index it seems you always select the highest value/ratio which means you will always use it. In the case of your example:
first choice is value=120, weight 30 so there remains 20.

Then you select again value=120 but this time you take 2/3 of its value to fit which is 80

This is why you get 200.

You need to fix your code so you don't select the same item all the time. The easiest way is to use a priority queue with deleteMin or deleteMax